# On Prem SharePoint Hosted Add-ins Not Working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-hosted-app

My Add-in challenges me for my credentials; even though I'm already authenticated by SharePoint.  After 3 times, a blank page is displayed; even though my default.aspx is not a blank page.  How can I fix this?

I am attempting to setup my VM so I can develop SharePoint Hosted Add-ins.  I followed the tutorial below.  Next I create a new solution in Visual Studio:

1. Project Type: SharePoint Add-in (Visual C#)
2. How do you want to host your SharePoint Add-in?: SharePoint-hosted
3. What's the earliest version of SharePoint that you want your add-in to target?: SharePoint 2013
4. Project is created
5. Debug the Solution
6. SharePoint asks if I want to trust the Add-in
7. After accepting, I am challenged for my credentials
8. After 3 attempts, a blank page is displayed

[image: step 8, a blank page is displayed]
My Environment

- Solution Name: addins__Cross_SC
- SharePoint   : 2013
- Visual Studio: 2017
- Windows      : 2012 R2

Tutorial

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-up-an-on-premises-development-environment-for-sharepoint-add-ins?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Did you configure your farm for add-ins? That is, did you create a domain for add-ins, configure your DNS, and setup the add-in service applications?

Comment: I registered a domain and prefix in PowerShell; the values are in Central Admin.  I made it to the end of the instructions in the link below.  I didn't see anything about setting up DNS.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-up-an-on-premises-development-environment-for-sharepoint-add-ins?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I have a bit of improvement; I can't reach my add-in from a browser on my Host but I can from my VM. I set DisableLoopbackCheck (link below).  I've tried setting up a Forward Lookup in DNS but it isn't working.  https://sharepointsolutiontips.blogspot.com/2016/07/disable-loop-back-check-in-sharepoint.html